# Animate object to move based on modulation of a sound?

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to animate an object (mouth, eyebrow and some other expressions) to move in accordance to incoming sound. I was thinking to read sound modulation and detect changes and to animate movement of objects.

Is this a good approach?

If not, how should I approach to coding such feature? Does this have to be done in OpenGL or I can use Android SDK and its animations?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean Frequency Modulation, as opposed to Amplitude Modulation?  Perhaps a combination of both?  That might be pretty neat.  I don't think there's any reason NOT do to this...

As to whether its a "good" approach or not?  I think it might be pretty cool.

The android SDK has pretty robust animation built in at this point.  You should be able to do the animations using the SDK just fine.  If you get to the point where you really want to go wild with it you might need to step down a layer for speed concerns.

Look at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163446/what-is-the-best-2d-game-engine-for-android/17166794#17166794

For a pretty robust coverage of 2d Games in Android, which might point you in the right direciton.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting idea. I think there are two parts to the problem: input (sound) and output (graphics). For the graphics side, I don't think you need OpenGL per se. You could check out this guide to game development: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/the-abcs-of-android-game-development-prepare-the-canvas/2157/
I think it is relevant because it deals with moving graphics in real time.

For the sound, it would be nice to have an integer based on the frequency and modulation of the sound. For analyzing the sound, perhaps this library could help you out: http://code.google.com/p/musicg/
It can: 
- Read amplitude-time domain data
- Read frequency-time domain data

Then, you could progress through the amplitude data of a sound in real time and update the graphics accordingly.